# Create a variable based on time difference between dates on consecutive rows

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing

I have a very large set of data driven off of an id and a date.  The dataset has several hundred million rows and about 10 million id's.  I am running in a non-windows environment with ample RAM and multiple processors available.  I am doing this in parallel.  At the moment, I'm working with multidplyr, though am considering all options.

For illustration:

```
> df[1:11,]
          id       date gap episode
1  100000019 2015-01-24   0       1
2  100000019 2015-02-20  27       1
3  100000019 2015-03-31  39       2
4  100000019 2015-04-29  29       2
5  100000019 2015-05-27  28       2
6  100000019 2015-06-24  28       2
7  100000019 2015-07-24  30       2
8  100000019 2015-08-23  30       2
9  100000019 2015-09-21  29       2
10 100000019 2015-10-22  31       3
11 100000019 2015-12-30  69       4
```

The data is sorted before the function call.  The order is important. For each id, after the first date, I need to determine the number of days between each subsequent date.  I call this a gap.  So, the first date for the id gets a gap of zero.  The second date gets the value of the second date minus the date in the prior row.  An so on.

I am splitting the data by id, then sending the data for each id to the following function.

```
assign_gap <- function(x) {
  #  x$gap <- NA
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    x[i, ]$gap <- ifelse(i == 1, 0, x[i,]$date - x[i-1, ]$date)
  }
  return(x)
}

cluster <- create_cluster(8)
cluster_assign_value(cluster, 'assign_gap', assign_gap)
system.time(df <- df %>% partition(id, cluster = cluster) %>% do(assign_gap(.)) %>% collect())
```

I then apply another function that groups the sequence of gaps across dates into "episodes" based on allowable_gap (I am using a value of 30).  So, each id will potentially have multiple episodes assigned based on the date sequence and the gap.

```
assign_episode <- function(x, allowable_gap){
  ep <- 1
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    ifelse(x[i,]$gap <= allowable_gap, ep <- ep, ep <- ep + 1)
    x[i, ]$episode <- ep
  }
  return(x)
}

cluster <- create_cluster(8)
cluster_assign_value(cluster, 'assign_episode', assign_episode)
cluster_assign_value(cluster, 'allowable_gap', allowable_gap)
system.time(df <- df %>% partition(id, cluster = cluster) %>% do(assign_episode(., allowable_gap)) %>% collect())
```

Given the amount of data I have, I'd really like to find a way to avoid these loops in the functions, which I expect will improve efficiency considerably.  If anyone can think of an alternative that accomplishes the same thing, I would be grateful.

Comment: The `cumsum(...diff(...` idiom may be useful. Like `x <- c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11)`; `c(1, cumsum(diff(x) > 2) + 1)`.

Comment: diff hadn't occurred to me.  that's very helpful.  thank you

Comment: Regarding "_I am splitting the data by id_" and given the size of your data, you should really have a look at `data.table` and do the `cumsum(diff(...` `by = id` instead. Check the nice vignettes [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Thanks.  I will benchmark a data.table approach on a sample before I attempt running this on the full dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `data.table` library. This library is extremely fast, particularly if one is working with large data sets like yours. Here is a partial solution, where I solve the first step of your question:

#### 1. calculate `gap` between dates, making sure the first row of each `id` is 0

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, gap := c(0L, diff(date)) , by = id ]
```

Even though this is not working in parallel, I would expect this code to be faster than the loop you're currently using.

#### 2. Assign a group `episode` for consecutive observations when the `gap` is under `30` by `id`

I haven't found a solution for the second part of your question yet, but I would encourage others to complement this answer if they find a solution.